# flahvars seekbar problem

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, components, flashvars

Hi
I have a php page that echo's
some variables in to the flashvars of a video player swf file  the flashvar "vid_file_name" is loaded and plays

But for some reason the seekbar wont work properly
when I hard code, into the php page or    fla file it works fine
but when echoed in the php page it fails

it doesnt seem to be an encoding issue

I placed a text field in the swf file and the file name displays
And as stated before the "vid_file_name" var is imported and plays the video
it's just when it comes to the seekbar
code:

```
 import fl.video.*;


// Set Variables

var flvControl:FLVPlayback = auditionVid;
var flashVars = this.loaderInfo.parameters;
var flvSource:String = "http://www.mysite.co.uk/uploads/live/"+String(flashVars.vid_file_name);
var pageURL:String=ExternalInterface.call('window.document.location.toString');
var baseURL:String ="http://www.mysite.co.uk/";
var pageToGoTo:URLRequest;
gotoPageBtn.visible = false;
gotoPageBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,pageHandler)
gotoPageBtn.buttonMode = true;
function pageHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void{
     pageToGoTo =  new URLRequest(baseURL+"audition.php?user_id="+flashVars.user_id+"&vid_id="+flashVars.vid_id+"&vid_file_name="+flashVars.vid_file_name);
    navigateToURL(pageToGoTo, "_self");
```

}
        if(pageURL==baseURL||pageURL.indexOf(".co.uk/index.php") > -1 ){
    gotoPageBtn.visible = true
}

```
function readyHandler(event:VideoEvent):void
```

{

// flvControl.play()
 flvControl.autoPlay = false;

}

```
flvControl.addEventListener(VideoEvent.READY, readyHandler);

flvControl.source = flvSource;
flvControl.bufferTime = Number(10);
flvControl.playPauseButton = playpausebtn; 
flvControl.muteButton = mutebtn; 
flvControl.seekBar = mySeekBar;
```

Does any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone 
I thought id answer my own question
in case anyone else comes across this problem.  upon further testing I found that it was the files and not the data that was in error
the seekbar component needs metadata from the flv in order to work

I am using ffmpeg to convert the files to flv on upload by executing:
exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '.$uploadFile.' -f flv '.$new_flv.'');

this was insuficient, what I needed to use was something called flvtool2

I changed the command accordingly to:
exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '.$uploadFile.' -f flv - | flvtool2 -U stdin '.$new_flv.'');

notice the " - | flvtool2 -U stdin "
this so far has cured the problem

the strange thing is that the orignal command worked at first!

I just hope this can help others

Thanks again to JornC